# convert given string datetime2(7) in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am getting date time in  string format `2020-08-19T08:00:53.643Z` .

I need to convert this into datetime2(7) format i.e `2020-01-20 21:10:11.4866667`.

how can I do that with powershell

currently I am using this

```
$lastExectedTime= Get-Date $temp -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"
```

Comment: Since the original timestamp has only three fractions of a second, the precision is lost already. Maybe edit the question and show with more details what you are doing with the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using something similar to Daniel Björks answer (using `Parse` method from `[datetime]`)

```
C:\> ([datetime]::Parse("2020-08-19T08:00:53.643Z")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")
2020-08-19 10:00:53.6430000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
([DateTime]"2020-08-19T08:00:53.643Z").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")
```